# How can I repair a chip in partical board table top?

Tags: repair, wooden-furniture

I got [this table](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S19855480) from IKEA, and it was delivered with damage in it, unfortunately I did not recognize it as I had to check 10 packages but this is another story.

As you can see in the picture[image: damage in the table] there is a part that was chopped away.

How can I fix this?

Is there a way I can do it WITHOUT cutting (since I do not have the tools for it)?

NOTE: The Swatch is there for a size reference.

---

**UPDATE**
I've managed to get a similar product and filled the crack with it. I'll post the results tomorrow :)

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
IKEA replaced the table after 9 months because of my rigorous phone calls and complaints.

Comment: I suggest contacting Ikea - unless it's months after you took delivery. They may well replace the table saving you a job.

Comment: I am seconding Chris's idea, primarily because of the materials ikea uses.  You've got a laminate over particle board.  If you use a filler as suggested below, you'll have a heck of a time matching the color/texture of the rest of the table.  If you recently purchased the table, make Ikea "Make things right."  They tend to be very good customer-service-wise around here, and I'd suspect you'll have no problems getting the table replaced.

Comment: Yeah if that's a new piece then definitely ignore my answer below at least until you can get over to Ikea and request a replacement table top.

Comment: Well, i contacted IKEA about this, since the cargo came already damaged, they are suggesting that they can't do anything about it (they aren't even offering me a discount for another purchase, which would have been fine) so the negation with IKEA is off the table. Such a sad world.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Home Depot or Lowes, in the counter department, pick up some white SeamFil, a putty knife and both some coarse (80 grit) and some fine (220 grit) sand paper.

Sand out the gouge, apply the SeamFil and use the putty knife to smooth it.

After its dried, sand with the fine grit sand paper.

[SeamFil](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=seamfil&hl=en&prmd=imvns&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&biw=1480&bih=798&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=2921588551243717317&sa=X&ei=nEd3TsruGsLr0gHNk43nDQ&ved=0CEoQ8wIwAA)

Comment: Seems to be interesting enough. I want to try that. SeamFil looks like a product name, how can i ask for alternatives if the person does not SeamFil?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good experiment would be with auto-body filler. It dries to a hard resin plastic like finish as opposed to a porous puddy or wood filler.  My father uses it to fill the saw marks on auxiliary fences on his wood working power tools.